# IndexError: list index out of range Space invaders

Tags: python, loops

I wanted to create 1 extra enemy.I have a problem of looping through lists.But I keep getting this error when I do this:

```
enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here is my code:

```
num_of_enemies = 10
number = 1 
enemyX = []
enemyX_change = []
for i in range(num_of_enemies):
    enemyX.append(i)
    enemyX_change.append(3)

num_of_enemies += number
for i in range(num_of_enemies):
     enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]
```

Comment: after the first loop, the list has length 10, and then add 1 to `num_of_enemies` so when `i = 10` you will get an index error. Drop `num_of_enemies += number` or append another value to each list and it should be fixed

Comment: You added 10 elements to your list enemyX in the first loop. But later in your second loop you access enemyX[10] which simply does not exist. I would suggest you use the num_of_enemies for initially creating the list and using the len function for tracking the count further down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on one of your comments, you want to add a new enemy when collision happens.
Is this what you want?

```
num_of_enemies = 10
number = 1
enemyX = []
enemyX_change = []
for i in range(num_of_enemies):
    enemyX.append(i)
    enemyX_change.append(3)

for i in range(num_of_enemies):
    #Perform position change
    enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]
    #Add new enemy if more than one enemy has this position
    if enemyX.count(enemyX[i]) > 1:
        #Arrays start from zero (last index in list is num_of_enemies - 1)
        enemyX.append(num_of_enemies)
        enemyX_change.append(3)
        num_of_enemies += 1
```

Comment: Thank you!But before you answered I figure it out!So I added another variable called:
"num_of_enemies_full = 100" , maximum of enemies and I kept adding more enemies

Answer (score 1):

The first loop ends with `enemyX` having 10 elements.

You then add 1 to `num_of_enemies`, and try to change 11 elements of `enemyX`.

Answer (score 1):

In the first loop, you add ten (the value of `num_of_enemies`) enemies to `enemyX`. Then, by adding `number` to `num_of_enemies`, num_of_enemies becomes 11. But, in that second loop, instead of appending a new enemy to `enemyX`, you are altering the current value at index `i`. So when this loop gets to the last value, you get an error, because there is no value at index 10 in `enemyX`.

Here's how I would change your code:

```
num_of_enemies = 10
number = 1 
enemyX = []
enemyX_change = []
for i in range(num_of_enemies):
    enemyX.append(i)
    enemyX_change.append(3)

for i in range(num_of_enemies):
     enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]
enemyX.append((num_of_enemies + number) + 3); //I'm adding 3 because that's what you've been adding as part of enemyX_change
```

Comment: I was working on a game there are 10 enemies = 'num_of_enemies', and I wanted to add 1 enemy each time one enemy collides,so your solution is helpful but unfortunately it didn`t help me for my project.

Comment: Sorry about that! It seems that you solved it though.